# How to display local images placed on client machine in HTML webpages

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon

How to display local images placed on client machine in HTML webpages hosted on a webserver

I'm having few images placed in `C:/Images` folder so path should be something `file:///C:/Images/1.jpg` for a `image 1.jpg`

I'm using the code `<img src="file:///C:/Images/1.jpg" />` in sample.html

sample.html when placed on local HDD, shows `1.jpg`, but when I put the `sample.html` file on a web server it doesn't display the image placed on my C: drive.

Is there any way to show images placed on client HDD from a HTML webpage placed on a web server?

I tried even iframe, but no luck.

**EDIT:** Can I show these images using userscript or firefox addon? I'm actually implementing this thing in my screensaver firefox addon.

Comment: your images must be on server other wise there is no way that you can access the images on the client's HDD

Comment: How do you think server is going to translate the image location when you give the link location like that?

Comment: The browser will only access local resources when the primary document is also located on the local resource. This is to help prevent cross-site scripting nastiness. It would be much better for your clients if all your images are located on the same server as your web pages.

Comment: @Morpheus That is what wizards are for... XD

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I knew that there is a no way around using regular javascript. Actually I'm trying to achieve this using a firefox addon. I should have mentioned about the firefox addon, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web pages aren't allowed to access file:/// URLs for security reasons, there is no way around this. However, if you make the same files accessible via another protocol - this can work. For example, you can put the following line into your add-on's `chrome.manifest` file:

> resource myaddon file:///C:/Images

This will create a [resource protocol alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#resource) pointing to that directory - and the resource protocol can be used by webpages. Meaning that the pages will be able to use the image `C:\Images\1.jpg` as `resource://myaddon/1.jpg`.

You can also [add resource protocol aliases dynamically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using#Programmatically_adding_aliases). Just make sure you make only images accessible in this way and not all disk content - you might be opening a security hole otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Use the File API which works on all browsers except IE.

A simple example of this would be:

```
function ShowImage(filepath){
    var reader=new FileReader(); // File API object
    reader.onload=function(event){
        document.getElementById('myimage').src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(filepath);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the src attribute is always in the context of the server that is serving the HTML content.  I don't think there is a way around that.

So in your example `<img src="file:///C:/Images/1.jpg" />` if the host is ip `1.1.1.1` and the client is ip `2.2.2.2`

then `src` would be pointing to `1.1.1.1\file://C:/images/1.jpg` *<--that's an example not a real protocol.*

Comment: That's non-sense, this is clearly an absolute URL and the browser doesn't interpret it as a relative one. Websites aren't allowed to use file:/// URLs for security reasons.