# How to change Image Src(logo) in firefox using Inspect Element

Tags: css, firefox

When i did inspect Element on one of the website logo. Image src is as follow.

src="/WSDNPortalTest/Content/themes/images/THP_img.jpg"

Now, I want to try different logo, that i have in my local machine folder.

Is it possible to do that? Advice me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to inspect and put up your local image. However, you can follow the following steps to achieve the desired result:

1. Put your image on Google Drive or any other storage server
2. Generate a sharable link for that image
3. Inspect the element in your browser
4. Change image src from src="/WSDNPortalTest/Content/themes/images/THP_img.jpg to src = "sharable-url-here.jpg"

This is how you can achieve the same effect

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but the change will only be valid in that Inspect-session on your local machine. The www would like quite different if it was that easy to change a website! ;-)

see also: [How to display local images placed on client machine in HTML webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391723/how-to-display-local-images-placed-on-client-machine-in-html-webpages)

BUT: you could save the entire page using File/Save As and then edit the code locally and replace the downloaded image with your own.