# How to set a resource in a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have basically the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391723/how-to-display-local-images-placed-on-client-machine-in-html-webpages). I have a page, accessed over the web (well, local intranet, if that matters), and it needs to reference images on the client's machine. I know those images are going to be in C:\pics. Internet Explorer lets you just reference them, but I'm having trouble printing properly with internet explorer, so I want to try firefox. The answer on that question says you can create a "`resource`" with a firefox add-on that pages will be able to reference. However, it doesn't seem to be working. I followed the guide for [how to make your first add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) and got the red border to work on mozilla sites. I tried editing that add-on to include a chrome.manifest file that just says this:

```
resource exposedpics file:///C:/pics
```

and then the page (an asp page) references exposedpics.

```
<img align=left border="0" src="resource:///exposedpics/<%=Request("Number")%>.jpg" style="border: 3 solid #<%=bordercolor%>" align="right" WIDTH="110" HEIGHT="110">
```

the page doesn't show the picture. If I go to View Image Info on the image, I'll see the address is "resource:///exposedpics/8593.jpg" (in my example where I input 8593), but it doesn't show the image here. (yes, the image does exist under c:\pics. if I go to file:///C:/pics/8593.jpg, it loads.)

so maybe I don't know how to use a chrome.manifest. (I'm not sure if I need to reference it somehow in my manifest.json, I'm not.) That stack overflow question also says it's possible to dynamically create resources. so I tried to make my manifest.json say:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "FirefoxPixExposer",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "allows websites to access C:\\pics",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["expose.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

and expose.js says

```
// Import Services.jsm unless in a scope where it's already been imported
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var resProt = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource")
                      .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIResProtocolHandler);

var aliasFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                          .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
aliasFile.initWithPath("file:///C:/pics");

var aliasURI = Services.io.newFileURI(aliasFile);
resProt.setSubstitution("ExposedPics", aliasURI);
```

but the same thing happens, the image doesn't display. I did notice that if I put `document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";` at the top of expose.js, I do see a border around the body, but if I move it to below the line `Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");` it doesn't show up. Therefore, I suspect the code to dynamically create a resource is broken.

What am I doing wrong? Ultimately, how can I get an image on the client's machine to show up on a page from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a WebExtensions so none of the APIs you are trying to use exist.

This includes `Components.utils.import`, `Components.classes` etc. You should read [Working with files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_files) on MDN to get an idea, what is still possible.

Comment: Given that link, it sounds like you're saying it's impossible. Is there a way to still write the other kid of Firefox add-on that would still have these APIs, or are they completely deprecated?

Comment: As of FF57 SDK APIs are completely removed.  https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/